# Error Java Jersey com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have two methods in java class which is defined as jersey resource containing the below methods

```
@Path("base_endpoint")
public class ComplaintSupportResource{

    @Post
    @Path("/endPoint")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response complaintRegister(ComplaintDTO caliamtDTO) {
        ComplaintResponseDTO response =complaintService.registerComplaint(caliamtDTO);
        return Response.ok(response).build();
    }
}
```

Here is the dto class :

@XmlRootElement
public class ComplaintDTO {

```
private String memberName;
private String email;
private String mobileNO;
private String complaintId;
private String claimNo;
private String complaintDetails;
private String policyNo;



public String getComplaintId() {
    return complaintId;
}
public void setComplaintId(String complaintId) {
    this.complaintId = complaintId;
}
public String getClaimNo() {
    return claimNo;
}
public void setClaimNo(String claimNo) {
    this.claimNo = claimNo;
}
public String getComplaintDetails() {
    return complaintDetails;
}
public void setComplaintDetails(String complaintDetails) {
    this.complaintDetails = complaintDetails;
}
public String getPolicyNo() {
    return policyNo;
}
public void setPolicyNo(String policyNo) {
    this.policyNo = policyNo;
}
public String getMemberName() {
    return memberName;
}
public void setMemberName(String memberName) {
    this.memberName = memberName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getMobileNO() {
    return mobileNO;
}
public void setMobileNO(String mobileNO) {
    this.mobileNO = mobileNO;
}
}
```

I am getting the below exception. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
    SEVERE: A sub-resource locator, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.xxx.xxx.xxxComplaintSupportResource.complaintRegister(com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ComplaintDTO), can not have an entity parameter. Try to move the parameter to the corresponding resource method.
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.xxx.xxx.xxxComplaintSupportResource.complaintRegister(com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ComplaintDTO) at parameter at index 0
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is wrong with below implementation. I have other endpoints also implemented i the same are working fine.

Comment: Can you update the code with import statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Post annotation is not correct may be you are importing from some other library they Jerysey @POST annotation is different and make sure you are importing the javax.ws.rs.POST.  change the @Post to @POST like :

```
   @Path("base_endpoint")
   public class ComplaintSupportResource{

    **@POST**
    @Path("/endPoint")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response complaintRegister(ComplaintDTO caliamtDTO) {
        ComplaintResponseDTO response =complaintService.registerComplaint(caliamtDTO);
        return Response.ok(response).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I spent all most 2 hours didn't figur out this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if following dependencies are present in build path

```
jersey-multipart.jar
mimepull.jar
```

If not try adding them to class path.

Other possible reason could be, same @Path annotation - @Path("/endPoint") with uri as "/endpoint" might be defined twice.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: they are in classpath and also endpoint is not defined any where else

Comment: I can see only one resource.

Comment: also version of jersey-multipart.jar should be same as of jersey version

Comment: Just paste the complete class